# Multiple with() function in Laravel Query: Laravel 5.2.37

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

**Model 1**

```
class RoleModel extends Model {

    public $table = 'tblrole';
    public $primaryKey = 'RoleID';
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function RoleBasedPermissions() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Role\RolePermissionModel', 'RoleID', 'RoleID');
    }
}
```

**Model 2**

```
class RolePermissionModel extends Model
{
    public $table = 'tblrolepermission';
    public $primaryKey = 'RolePermissionID';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function Permission() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Role\RolePermissionModel', 
            'PermissionID', 'PermissionID');
    }

    public function Role() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Role\RoleModel', 
            'RoleID', 'RoleID');
    }
}
```

**Model 3**

```
class PermissionModel extends Model
{
    public $table = 'tblpermission';
    public $primaryKey = 'PermissionID';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function Module() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Role\ModuleModel', 
            'ModuleID', 'ModuleID');
    }

    public function Action() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Role\ActionModel', 
            'ActionID', 'ActionID');
    }
}
```

**My Query is below**

```
$data = RoleModel
    ::where('RoleID', $RoleID)
    ->with('RoleBasedPermissions')
    ->with('RoleBasedPermissions.Permission')
    ->with('RoleBasedPermissions.Permission.Module')
    ->get();
```

**Error**

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::Module()

**Details**

Issue is in this Query part `->with('RoleBasedPermissions.Permission.Module')`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
public function Permission()
{
    return $this->hasOne(
        'App\Models\Role\PermissionModel', // <-- This is wrong in your code above
        'PermissionID',
        'PermissionID'
    );
}
```

Also, the other arguments probably need to be updated too.

---

BTW, you don't need those 3 calls to `with`. A single call will load the whole chain:

```php
$data = RoleModel::where('RoleID', $RoleID)
    ->with('RoleBasedPermissions.Permission.Module')
    ->get();
```